# How do you stream data from an input file when writing contracts on EOS?

Tags: smart-contract, action, database

I emulated the tic.tac.toe tutorial code and made a simple contract that allows me to add and remove car information. However, I can only push action one at a time and this only allows me to add/remove one entry of car data at a time. How do I stream data from an input file using push action (Could I use ifstream etc.?)? Does this exist in the EOS library?

Answer (score 1):

This is decentralized application so generally you can't push/pull outside data to/from it. 
That's also the reason why Oracle service is there to responsible for it.